# Exportar ionic creator

Tags: javascript, android, ionic, script, app

Estou desenvolvendo, depois de muito tempo, com o Ionic novamente. Bem, ao  preparar o ambiente corretamente e digitar no terminal

```
ionic start myapp blank
```

o código é gerado e funciona corretamente, quando faço o teste

```
ionic serve
```

porém, a pasta myapp não me gera a pasta www, ela só aparece quando adiciono a plataforma android... e ainda por cima vazia.

Estou querendo exportar meu código do ionic creator, mas quando copio na pasta www (vazia) nada acontece!
o que eu faço? como exportar do ionic creator para meu código, sem a pasta www?

Comment: Olá, na .zip que vc baixa o do Ionic Creator vem uma pasta src?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, se o seu projeto é Ionic 3 ou superior
substitua a pasta src do seu projeto  pela pasta do .zip ( do creator ).

Como informado no passo 2 da documentação:

> Now go into the newly created myApp directory, and you will see
>   directory called src inside.
>
> Copy and paste the contents from your zip export into the src
>   directory. You will want to overwrite the app directory, pages
>   directory, and index.html.

https://docs.usecreator.com/docs/zip-export-an-ionic-project

Comment: Certo, obrigado!